# Logout - have to hit button twice for it to work?

Tags: php, html

Trying to perform a logout from current page. Basically if you hit the logout, it will just show the login form again. I do not want to call a page doing this. When I execute the "Logout" button, it still shows the user logged in, but if I hit the "Logout" button a second time it works correctly. Or if I refresh the page it works also. Just seems the initial submitting of "Logout" does not refresh.

```html
<?
  session_start();

$subtitle="Login";
ob_start();
// require("header2.php");
//Get any form data.
$football->WhoOnlineDelete;

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
global $conn;
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","","", "");

function logOut()
{
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    unset($_SESSION['uname']);
 session_destroy();
    ob_start();
    exit();
}

if ($_POST)
{
//Make sure cookies are enabled.
 // if ($_COOKIE["football"]=="")
//  {

//      $football->ErrorMessage("You must use a browser that supports cookies and<br> have them enabled in order to access this site.");
//  }
//    else
//  {
//Check input.
    if ($username=="")
    {
                echo "Please enter a username.";
    }
        elseif ($password=="")
    {
                echo"Please enter your password.";
    }
      else
    {
//Verify the password and redirect to default page if correct.
     $sql=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from phpfb_users where user = '".$username."'");
         $row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
         $rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
      if($rows == 0)
      {
                echo "User '".$username."' not found.";
      }
      elseif (md5($password) != $row->password)
      {
                echo "Incorrect password, please reenter.";
      }
       else
      {

        $user=$row->user;
        if ($row->name =="") {
        $uname=$row->user;
        } else {
        $uname=$row->name;
        }
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        header("Location: loginJERRY.php");
      }

    }


  }


//}
  else
{
//Set test cookie.
  setcookie("football","peanutbutter",0,"/",$football->domain,0);
}
?>
<div>
<div style="display:block;margin:0px auto;" background-color="lightblue;">
<?php if(empty($_SESSION["user"])) { ?>
<form name="loginform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">

 <div class="error-message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div> 
 <div class="field-group">
  <div><label for="login">Username: </label>
  <input name="username" type="text" class="input-field">
 
<label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" class="input-field"> 
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="form-submit-button"></span></div>
 </div>       
</form>
<?php 
} else { 
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM phpfb_users WHERE user='".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");
 $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<br><br>
<form action="" method="post" id="frmLogout">
<div class="member-dashboard">Welcome <?php echo $user; ?>, You have successfully logged in!
 <input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout" class="logout-button"></div>
</form> 
<?
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    if ($_POST['logout'] == 'logout') {
logOut();
    } else if ($_POST['logout'] != 'logout') {
    }
    
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      document.loginform.username.focus();
      document.loginform.username.select();
</script>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't log them out until after the page has rendered the content...

Comment: Try changing the form action to something like `index.php` and see if that solves it. Or, if you want to bring the user back to the same page, then chuck an:

`if(isset($_POST['$var])` statement on to your form to check whether or not the data has been parsed yet. If it has, then don't output the form.

Comment: Your code is *very* vulnerable to hacking attacks. Please don't build this yourself. I would recommend that you use a pre-built component for a PHP framework (like Laravel).

Comment: Take the logout part on top or reload the page after logout again and it will work for sure, by clicking on the button you get logged out, the page just doesn't show it, press F5 and you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check logout functionality before you html page renders, so add you logout key in $_POST after logout() function like,

```
<?
    ..........    
    $conn = ....

    function logOut()
    {
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        unset($_SESSION['uname']);
        session_destroy();
        ob_start();
        exit();
    }
    if (isset($_POST['logout']) && $_POST['logout'] == 'logout') {
         logOut();
    } // not required else part here

    if($_POST) {
         ....
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the technical point of view the user is logged out (because the session variable is destroyed) but the page is showing something different. You need to take the logout part on top before the page gets rendered, otherwise the page doesn't know that the user is logged out:

```
<?
  session_start();

$subtitle="Login";
ob_start();
// require("header2.php");
//Get any form data.
$football->WhoOnlineDelete;

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
global $conn;
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","","", "");

function logOut()
{
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    unset($_SESSION['uname']);
    session_destroy();
    ob_start();
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    if ($_POST['logout'] == 'logout') {
logOut();
    } else if ($_POST['logout'] != 'logout') {
    }

}

if ($_POST)
{
//Make sure cookies are enabled.
 // if ($_COOKIE["football"]=="")
//  {

//      $football->ErrorMessage("You must use a browser that supports cookies and<br> have them enabled in order to access this site.");
//  }
//    else
//  {
//Check input.
    if ($username=="")
    {
                echo "Please enter a username.";
    }
        elseif ($password=="")
    {
                echo"Please enter your password.";
    }
      else
    {
//Verify the password and redirect to default page if correct.
     $sql=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from phpfb_users where user = '".$username."'");
         $row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
         $rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
      if($rows == 0)
      {
                echo "User '".$username."' not found.";
      }
      elseif (md5($password) != $row->password)
      {
                echo "Incorrect password, please reenter.";
      }
       else
      {

        $user=$row->user;
        if ($row->name =="") {
        $uname=$row->user;
        } else {
        $uname=$row->name;
        }
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        header("Location: loginJERRY.php");
      }

    }


  }


//}
  else
{
//Set test cookie.
  setcookie("football","peanutbutter",0,"/",$football->domain,0);
}
?>
<div>
<div style="display:block;margin:0px auto;" background-color="lightblue;">
<?php if(empty($_SESSION["user"])) { ?>
<form name="loginform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">

    <div class="error-message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>    
    <div class="field-group">
        <div><label for="login">Username: </label>
        <input name="username" type="text" class="input-field">

<label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input-field"> 
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="form-submit-button"></span></div>
    </div>       
</form>
<?php 
} else { 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM phpfb_users WHERE user='".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<br><br>
<form action="" method="post" id="frmLogout">
<div class="member-dashboard">Welcome <?php echo $user; ?>, You have successfully logged in!
 <input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout" class="logout-button"></div>
</form> 
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      document.loginform.username.focus();
      document.loginform.username.select();
</script>
```

You could also reload the page after calling the logout function, but this isn't very nice in my opinion. You always have to keep in mind that you first have to execute all the logic before you render the page.